# Haw to call method from class to aspx.cs

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, class

Class code:

```
 using System.Data.SqlClient;

    namespace WebApplication5
    {
        public class Class1
        {
            public int ID;
            public string nem;
            public int salar;


     public void ReadIMP(int id )
            {

                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=emp;Integrated Security=True");
                string Query = "select * from employee where Id = '" + id + "' ";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(Query, conn);
                conn.Open();

                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    ID = (int)reader["Id"];
                    nem = (string)reader["name"];
                    salar = (int)reader["salary"];
                }
                reader.Close();
                conn.Close();

                }


            }

}
```

aspx.cs code:

```
     protected void Read_IMP(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

                try
                {
                    Class1 class1 = new Class1();

                    class1.ReadIMP(Convert.ToInt16(TextBox1.Text));

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    LabelEX.Text = ex.Message;

                }


            }
```

aspx code:

```
    <div>
             enter the id of employees :

            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>  
            <br />
                        Id of employees is

                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>

             <br />
                        name of employees is

                        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server"></asp:Label>

             <br />
                              salary of employee is :

                        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server"></asp:Label>


                           <asp:Button ID="Button4" runat="server" Text="Search"   OnClick="Read_IMP" />

             <br />

            <asp:Label ID="LabelEX" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
```

.............................................................................
I'am using method in class to retrieve data from database and calling the method in aspx.cs page 
I want to filling these attributes: ID , nem , salar into Label1 , Label2 ,Label3 haw can i do it

Comment: Did you try to assign the three public field of class1 to your three labels text property? _Label2.Text = class1.nem;_

Comment: You just assign the values of you class properties to either the Text or Label property of the UI elements.

Comment: The `readIMP()` is vulnerable to sql injection attacks, even though it only uses an `int`. Go parameterized queries, or go home.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code, you already fill data in fields, let those data fill on your `aspx` control directly

```
Class1 class1 = new Class1();
class1.ReadIMP(Convert.ToInt16(TextBox1.Text));
Label1.Text = (string)class1.ID;
Label2.Text = class1.nem;
Label3.Text = (string)class1.salar;
```